# Struct alignment is always 4

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pragma-pack

Why pragma pack does not work in here? `sizeof()` returning the size aligned to 4. I use compiler which comes with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

```
#pragma pack(push,1)

struct Header {
    uint16_t zero = 0;
    uint32_t id{};
};

struct ImageBlock : Header {
    uint32_t currentValidLength{};
};

#pragma pack(pop)
constexpr int sz = sizeof(ImageBlock);  // returns 12 but should be 10
```

Tried to also set `Struct member alignment (/Zp1)` compiler option with no luck

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to a [mre]? I doubt that a structure of size `1260` with that many different members is actually required to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, I got 1258, but admittedly with different compiler versions.

Comment: Still [could not reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/3a7dc3oY7)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's an IntelliSense bug. At runtime, the size is correct, but Visual Studio shows me an incorrect value of `sz` while editing. I've also tried `static_assert` on the size: VS shows that it will fail at compile time, but in fact, everything is ok.